# How to understand [] in data type definition in numba

Tags: python, numba

I'm looking at python code working with numba, and have some questions. There is less tutorial on numba, so that I come here to ask.

In numba, data type is pre-declared to help processing. I'm not clear on the rule to declare data type. One example is `numba.float64[:,::1]`. I feel it's declaring a 2D array in float type. However, I'm not sure what `::1` means here. Another example is `nb.types.NPDatetime('M')[::1]`. Is it slicing the 1D array?

I still have questions on `ListType()`, which is imported from `numba.types`. Only one element is allowed here? In my code, one class type is saved and passed to `ListType()` as single argument. What if I need to explicitly define this class type, and pass it here? Thanks.

I feel there is few tutorial or documents on numba module. If ok, please share some resources on numba. That's very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One example is `numba.float64[:,::1]`. I feel it's declaring a 2D array in float type. However, I'm not sure what `::1` means here

Exactly. `::1` means that the array axis is *contiguous*. This enable further optimizations like the use of SIMD instructions.

> Another example is `nb.types.NPDatetime('M')[::1]`. Is it slicing the 1D array?

`nb.types.NPDatetime('M')` is a Numpy datetime type (where `'M'` is meant to specify the *granularity* of the datetime. eg. months) here and `[::1]` means that this is a 1D contiguous array (containing datetime objects).

One should not be confused between object *instances* and object *types*. In Python, this is quite frequent to mix both but this is due to the dynamic nature of the language. Statically-typed compiled languages like C or C++ clearly separate the two concepts and types cannot be manipulated at runtime.

> Only one element is allowed here?

`ListType` is a class representing the type of a typed list. Its *unique parameter* defines the type of the item in the resulting type of list. For example `nb.types.ListType(nb.types.int32)` returns an object representing the type of a typed list containing 32-bit integers. Note that it is *not* a list instance. It is meant to be provided to Numba signature or other types.

Comment: Thanks. Jerome R. Could you please share some numba learning sources?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have much. I learned Numba by reading the documentation, doing project with it, reading issues (and a bit the Numba code which is not very user-friendly) on github and reading other StackOverflow answers. That's all.